# Save the screenshot of an application into a bitmap

Tags: windows, screenshot

I am working on a problem, where in I am trying to save the screenshot of a window(including the title bar and borders) to a PNG file. For certain applications like Google Chrome and Visual Studio, I am not able to get the complete window's image that we get with Alt + PrintScreen.

The issues are:

1. For Google Chrome, I am not getting the Minimize, Maximize and Close buttons
2. For Visual Studio, I am getting only certain parts and missing Solution Explorer and Output windows.

I have made sure the handle I use is the root window's handle

Below is the code I use to get the BitMap:

```
hdc = GetDCEx(hwnd, 0, DCX_WINDOW);
hDest = CreateCompatibleDC (hdc);

GetWindowRect (hwnd, &rt);
hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap (hdc, rt.right - rt.left, rt.bottom - rt.top);
SelectObject(hDest, hBitmap);
BitBlt( hDest, 0, 0, rt.right - rt.left, rt.bottom - rt.top, hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
```

Thanks,
Raaja

Comment: You might want to try other screen-capture applications to see if they have the same problem.  If they have the same problem then the application of the captured window is probably doing something strange.  Try it with Greenshot (http://greenshot.org/), see what it gives.  If it does work with Greenshot, you could try to take a look at its source code, since it's open source.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. Greenshot was giving a clear screenshot of the windows, but they use the same code that I use for the capture. Below is their code:


IntPtr hdcSrc = User32.GetWindowDC(handle);

IntPtr hdcDest = GDI32.CreateCompatibleDC(hdcSrc);

IntPtr hBitmap = GDI32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcSrc,width,height);

IntPtr hOld = GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest,hBitmap);

GDI32.BitBlt(hdcDest,0,0,width,height,hdcSrc,left,top,GDI32.SRCCOPY);

Comment: Patrick, in Greenshot, however they do not capture the window, rather they capture the portion of the screen covered by the specified window. Hence, they do not use the window's handle rather they use the desktop's handle and crop the region covered by the window. Thanks,